# What are the known upper bounds for $\sum_{d\leq x} a_{d}F(x/d)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose that $a_d$ is a sequence of numbers such that $\sum_{d\leq N} |a_d| \ll \sqrt{N}$ and $F(N) \ll N(\log (N))^{-c}$ for some constant $c>1$. What are the known upper bounds for $f(x):=\sum_{d\leq x} a_{d} F(x/d)$ ? I'm aware of Axer's theorem which asserts that $f(x) =o(x)$, but is there any sharper result ?

Comment: Are you sure that Axer's theorem applies? The form I have found online requires that $F(N)=O(1)$

Comment: @MiloMoses, i'm not sure of the form you found online, but you can see Theorem 8.1 of Montgomery-Vaughan.

Comment: And what's your difficulty? Clearly, the worst case scenario is $a_d=\frac 1{\sqrt d}, F(N)=N/\log^c N$ with the asymptotic like $x/\log^c x$. Am I misunderstanding something in the question?